# How to get list of EC2 instances with Amazon PHP SDK 2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

How to get list of Amazon EC2 instances matching some filters using [AWS SDK for PHP 2](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_describeInstances) method for this. Let's cover this with some more details.

You need to get Ec2Client instance first. The easiest way to initialize the client:

```
$config = array();
$config['key'] = 'key';
$config['secret'] = 'secret';
$config['region'] = 'us-east-1';
$config['version'] = 'latest'; // Or Specified
$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);
```

And then just call `DescribeInstances` method.

```
$result = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances(array(
        'Filters' => array(
                array('Name' => 'instance-type', 'Values' => array('m1.small')),
        )
));
```

You can get list of available filters on the Amazon [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html) API method page.

But wait, what might be difficult here?

- Note the parameter name `Filters`. In the API it is called `Filter`
- Parameter `Values` is called different from API and it is an array

Yes, this is all described in the documentation. But if you look at some [Old API usage samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198612/how-to-programmatically-get-public-dns-of-an-instance) you can see that the syntax has changed and this might be really hard to notice what have to be updated in that examples to make things working.

And to complete the example let me show some simple output of the results.

```
$reservations = $result['Reservations'];
foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
    $instances = $reservation['Instances'];
    foreach ($instances as $instance) {

        $instanceName = '';
        foreach ($instance['Tags'] as $tag) {
            if ($tag['Key'] == 'Name') {
                $instanceName = $tag['Value'];
            }
        }


        echo 'Instance Name: ' . $instanceName . PHP_EOL;
        echo '---> State: ' . $instance['State']['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '---> Instance ID: ' . $instance['InstanceId'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '---> Image ID: ' . $instance['ImageId'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '---> Private Dns Name: ' . $instance['PrivateDnsName'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '---> Instance Type: ' . $instance['InstanceType'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo '---> Security Group: ' . $instance['SecurityGroups'][0]['GroupName'] . PHP_EOL;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried the above and get "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\\Ec2\\Ec2Client' not found in /var/www/functions/ec2_instances.php on line 9"  .. Line 9 being the $ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);  bit. I've done: include "aws/sdk.class.php";  on the first line, and the sdk is in a subfolder "aws". I tried prefixing with \aws\ too and didn't work. Ideally the sdk folder would be outside of the project, but I moved it there thinking it was a pathing issue. Any thoughts on what to change?  Full gist: https://gist.github.com/nodeGarden/db707771faf12f7db47a

Comment: @mondo Hello. I think you are using [AWS SDK version 1](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php) My question and code example is for [AWS SDK version 2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) I suggest to [install AWS using composer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/installation.html). Warm regards, Victor.

Comment: It was indeed v1. I went with the Composer install, and works now. It has been printing out for a good 5 minutes now, and eventually crashed Chrome. Is the response really that big? Or did I likely get stuck in some infinite loop?  ... [edit] Looks like the print_r is the culprit. Took that out and it works. Only prints one, but I'm sure I can fix that.

Comment: I get this when I try the code above Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate' in D:\proiecte\PHP\www\wpec2\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Common\AwsClient.php on line 275

GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in D:\proiecte\PHP\www\wpec2\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 51

Comment: One thing I noticed is that in the latest update (from Amazon side) not from API, now you can apply this PHP api methods only for the region you are connected.

Answer (score 3):

Victor's answer is great, but it wasn't working for me because I was missing one line:

```
$reservations=$result->toArray();
```

The Amazon PHP SDK 2 returns Guzzle Model objects for many things (including this), and they need to be converted to arrays before foreach will work.  More info here:

http://guzzlephp.org/api/class-Guzzle.Service.Resource.Model.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've updated my answer. Guzzle Model can be accessed as array like this `$reservations = $result['Reservations'];` or with `get()` method `$reservations = $result->get('Reservations');`. In both cases you would get an array as result. The result's structure is described in the API. Warm regards, Victor

Answer (score 1):

that was of wonderful help Victor,
hey voidstin, that was not required in my case [$reservations=$result->toArray();]

```
require "aws.phar";

use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region; 

$aws = Ec2Client::factory(array(
'key' => 'XXXXXX',  //Your key and secret key are found at https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials
'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
'region' => 'XXXXXX'  //This is the server cluster we are connecting to.  US_EAST_1 is Northern Virginia.  US_WEST_1 is Northern California.  US_WEST_2 is Oregon
));

$result = $aws->DescribeInstances();

$reservations = $result['Reservations'];
foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
$instances = $reservation['Instances'];
foreach ($instances as $instance) {
$instanceName = '';
foreach ($instance['Tags'] as $tag) {
if ($tag['Key'] == 'Name') {
$instanceName = $tag['Value'];
}
}
echo 'Instance Name: ' . $instanceName . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> State: ' . $instance['State']['Name'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Instance ID: ' . $instance['InstanceId'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Image ID: ' . $instance['ImageId'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Private Dns Name: ' . $instance['PrivateDnsName'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Instance Type: ' . $instance['InstanceType'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '---> Security Group: ' . $instance['SecurityGroups'][0]['GroupName'] . PHP_EOL;
echo '<br>';
echo '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With purpose to get list of `PublicDnsName` you can use this code:

```
use Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client;

$ec2 = Ec2Client::factory($config);
$args = [
    'Filters' => [
        ['Name' => 'tag:Name', 'Values' => ['*{{your-tag}}*']],
    ]
];
$data = $ec2->DescribeInstances($args)->toArray();
$instances = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, function ($value, $key) use (&$instances) {
    if ($key === 'PublicDnsName') {
        $instances[$value] = true;
    }
});
var_export($instances);
```

You will receive something like this:

```
array (
  'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' => true,
  'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' => true,
  'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' => true,
  'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' => true,
  'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' => true,
  'ec2-*-*-*-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' => true,
)
```