# AWS SDK for PHP Example?

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pear

I am trying to install the AWS SDK for PHP on my (of all things) AWS EC2 server. I *think* I have it installed, but can't seem to figure out how to use it. All of the code examples I can find are for S3. I'm looking for a **PHP Code Example for using the AWS SDK for PHP v2.x to do *anything* with Amazon EC2**.

Even if it just lists my currently running instances. Nothing fancy, I just need to see it work.

I've installed the SDK using Pear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Victor Smirnow has already taken the time to provide a question and elaborate answer on [How to get list of EC2 instances with Amazon PHP SDK 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233914/45773) (+1 each) - accordingly you should simply check his answer for more details, but the short version for using the [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html) API action via the AWS SDK for PHP 2 [describeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_describeInstances) method as requested boils down to:

```
$config = array();
$config['key'] = 'key';
$config['secret'] = 'secret';
$config['region'] = 'us-east-1';
$ec2Client = \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client::factory($config);

$result = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances();
```

Comment: @andrebruton - have a look at the standard PHP [print()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the User Guide? There's a [Quick Start](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html) and here's the [guide for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html).

Comment: Yep, I've seen the User Guide. I'm looking for a guide/code examples for EC2.