# Get Instances from AWS - Amazon Web Services

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I want to get Instances from AWS.

Here is my function:

```
$ec2Client = Ec2Client::factory(array(
'version' => '2015-10-01',
'region'  => 'us-east-1',
'credentials' => array(
'key' => 'key',
'secret'  => 'secret',
)
));
$result = $ec2Client->DescribeInstances();
```

I expect following result as specified in:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html?r=2119#API_DescribeInstances_Errors:

```
<DescribeInstancesResponse xmlns="http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2015-10-01/">
  <requestId>fdcdcab1-ae5c-489e-9c33-4637c5dda355</requestId>
    <reservationSet>
      <item>
        <reservationId>r-1a2b3c4d</reservationId>
        <ownerId>123456789012</ownerId>
        <groupSet>
          <item>
            <groupId>sg-1a2b3c4d</groupId>
            <groupName>my-security-group</groupName>
          </item>
        </groupSet>
        <instancesSet>
          <item>
            <instanceId>i-1a2b3c4d</instanceId>
            <imageId>ami-1a2b3c4d</imageId>
            <instanceState>
              <code>16</code>
              <name>running</name>
            </instanceState>
            <privateDnsName/>
            <dnsName/>
            <reason/>
            <keyName>my-key-pair</keyName>
            <amiLaunchIndex>0</amiLaunchIndex>
            <productCodes/>
            <instanceType>c1.medium</instanceType>
            <launchTime>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000</launchTime>
            <placement>
              <availabilityZone>us-west-2a</availabilityZone>
              <groupName/>
              <tenancy>default</tenancy>
            </placement>
            <platform>windows</platform>
            <monitoring>
              <state>disabled</state>
            </monitoring>
            <subnetId>subnet-1a2b3c4d</subnetId>
            <vpcId>vpc-1a2b3c4d</vpcId>
            <privateIpAddress>10.0.0.12</privateIpAddress>
            <ipAddress>46.51.219.63</ipAddress>
            <sourceDestCheck>true</sourceDestCheck>
            <groupSet>
              <item>
                <groupId>sg-1a2b3c4d</groupId>
                <groupName>my-security-group</groupName>
              </item>
            </groupSet>
            <architecture>x86_64</architecture>
            <rootDeviceType>ebs</rootDeviceType>
            <rootDeviceName>/dev/sda1</rootDeviceName>
            <blockDeviceMapping>
              <item>
                <deviceName>/dev/sda1</deviceName>
                <ebs>
                  <volumeId>vol-1a2b3c4d</volumeId>
                  <status>attached</status>
                  <attachTime>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ</attachTime>
                  <deleteOnTermination>true</deleteOnTermination>
                </ebs>
              </item>
            </blockDeviceMapping>
            <virtualizationType>hvm</virtualizationType>
            <clientToken>ABCDE1234567890123</clientToken>
            <tagSet>
              <item>
                <key>Name</key>
                <value>Windows Instance</value>
              </item>
            </tagSet>
            <hypervisor>xen</hypervisor>
            <networkInterfaceSet>
              <item>
                <networkInterfaceId>eni-1a2b3c4d</networkInterfaceId>
                <subnetId>subnet-1a2b3c4d</subnetId>
                <vpcId>vpc-1a2b3c4d</vpcId>
                <description>Primary network interface</description>
                <ownerId>123456789012</ownerId>
                <status>in-use</status>
                <macAddress>1b:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f</macAddress>
                <privateIpAddress>10.0.0.12</privateIpAddress>
                <sourceDestCheck>true</sourceDestCheck>
                <groupSet>
                  <item>
                    <groupId>sg-1a2b3c4d</groupId>
                    <groupName>my-security-group</groupName>
                  </item>
                </groupSet>
                <attachment>
                  <attachmentId>eni-attach-1a2b3c4d</attachmentId>
                  <deviceIndex>0</deviceIndex>
                  <status>attached</status>
                  <attachTime>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+0000</attachTime>
                  <deleteOnTermination>true</deleteOnTermination>
                </attachment>
                <association>
                  <publicIp>198.51.100.63</publicIp>
                  <ipOwnerId>123456789012</ipOwnerId>
                </association>
                <privateIpAddressesSet>
                  <item>
                    <privateIpAddress>10.0.0.12</privateIpAddress>
                    <primary>true</primary>
                    <association>
                      <publicIp>198.51.100.63</publicIp>
                      <ipOwnerId>123456789012</ipOwnerId>
                    </association>
                  </item>
                  <item>
                    <privateIpAddress>10.0.0.14</privateIpAddress>
                    <primary>false</primary>
                    <association>
                      <publicIp>198.51.100.177</publicIp>
                      <ipOwnerId>123456789012</ipOwnerId>
                    </association>
                  </item>
                </privateIpAddressesSet>
              </item>
            </networkInterfaceSet>
          </item>
        </instancesSet>
      </item>
    </reservationSet>
    </DescribeInstancesResponse>
```

But I am getting following result:

```
Aws\Result Object ( [data:Aws\Result:private] => Array ( [Reservations] => Array ( ) [@metadata] => Array ( [statusCode] => 200 [effectiveUri] => https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com [headers] => Array ( [content-type] => text/xml;charset=UTF-8 [transfer-encoding] => chunked [vary] => Accept-Encoding [date] => Fri, 27 Nov 2015 07:03:59 GMT [server] => AmazonEC2 ) ) ) )
```

I dont know how to get expected result. Can i get any help?

thanks.

Comment: are your instances in us-east-1 ?

Comment: yes. instances are in us-east-1

Comment: This post has done that with php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233913/how-to-get-list-of-ec2-instances-with-amazon-php-sdk-2

Comment: i tried with this way already. i am getting empty array when i print $reservations.

Comment: if you have a linux machine, you can quickly install awscli and check the output before narrowing out the problem in php. It will take less than 5 mins.
You can install using 'sudo apt-get install awscli'. Then do 'aws configure' and set the key, secret and region. You can leave the output format blank. Then run 'aws ec2 describe-instances'. If you get the expected output this way, then something wrong with your php setup.

Comment: i dont have linux machine. i am having windows. am i getting correct output? if yes means, how can i get ip address, health status?

Comment: For windows, you can use: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-msi-on-windows

Comment: If you have instances, then it should be displayed. I am not sure why it is not displaying, hence asking you to try with awscli to know whether the problem is with php or something else.

Answer (score 0):

2 things here:

- you have the AWS SDK which is what you listed at the first link
- you have the PHP SDK which is build on top of the AWS SDK.

You will not receive the SDK answer (ie the XML) when going through the PHP SDK. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2015-10-01.html#describeinstances for what the PHP sdk returns.

Comment: ok. how can i get ip address, health status and api version from php sdk. ?